# JUnit Mocito Sprinboot UnitTest failing

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit5

I am trying to write a unit test for a service layer method that should return a message if the item queried isn't found in the DB. The test I've written is failing and I'm not sure why.

I'm using Springboot 2.1.6
Java 8

```
<!--Testing-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

TEST

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class HB357ServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private HB357Repository repository;

    @InjectMocks
    private HB357Service service;

@Test
    @DisplayName("ResponseId Does Not Exist")
    void testGetSurveyByResponseIdNotFound (){

        when(repository.findByResponseId("R_2agzc6I4T7TbPX0")).thenReturn(null);
        HB357 responseDoesntExist = service.getSurveyByResponseId("R_2agzc6I4T7TbPX0");
        assertEquals("Response ID not found", service.getSurveyByResponseId("R_2agzc6I4T7TbPX0") );
    }
```

I've also tried changing the `assertEquals` to 
`assertEquals(null, service.getSurveyByResponseId("R_2agzc6I4T7TbPX0"),Response ID not found" );`

SERVICE METHOD

```
public HB357 getSurveyByResponseId (String responseId){
            HB357 survey = hb357Repository.findByResponseId (responseId);
            if(survey == null){
                throw new InvalidIdException(responseId + " does not exist.");
            }

            return survey;
        }
```

The test fails by giving me the Invalid Exception rule written in the service layer - why isn't the test passing if what I'm testing for is that the Response ID doesn't exist?

Comment: show the service class method(getSurveyByResponseId) that u r calling

Comment: Add the complete stack trace please

Comment: @pvpkiran - I addded the service method

Comment: you are throwing an exception. You have to check if the exception is thrown. That cannot be donw via `assertEquals`

Comment: Thanks @pvpkiran - how is it checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you check if exception is thrown in Junit5

```
@Test
@DisplayName("ResponseId Does Not Exist")
void testGetSurveyByResponseIdNotFound (){

     when(repository.findByResponseId("R_2agzc6I4T7TbPX0")).thenReturn(null);
     InvalidIdException thrown = Assertions.assertThrows(InvalidIdException.class, () -> service.getSurveyByResponseId("R_2agzc6I4T7TbPX0"));
     assertTrue(thrown.getMessage().contains("does not exist"));
}
```